# Burden of proof of hirabah?

Tags: hudud, hirabah

As far as I know, hirabah is a hadd offense, and so I expect that it comes with a specific burden of proof. I'm unable to find sources that explain that burden of proof

**Question:** what burden of proof do the different madhahib require for hirabah?

Comment: Are you asking who's duty it is to provide the evidence? Or how many witnesses are required to prove it?

Comment: @Uma I mean what evidence is necessary for a conviction, be it testimony, confession, or other kinds of evidence.

Comment: Hirabah requires 2 witnesses

Answer (score 3):

The burden of proof for *hirābah* is not a matter that has a difference of opinions among scholars. Proof can be established through:

- *Al-Iqrār* (Arabic: الإقرار): Confession by the person committing *hirābah*, or
- *Al-Bayyinah* (Arabic: البينة): The testimony of two witnesses provided certain conditions are met.

The conditions for the witnesses are that they:

- Be of sound mind
- Be among the criminals, victims, or witnesses through presence
- Testify only against others (witnesses cannot testify against themselves, as this would be *iqrār*).

The *hadd* of *hirābah* is invalidated in the following cases (in which case *ta'zīr* takes place instead based on the judge's view of the case):

- Having only one witness
- Having one mail witness and one female witness
- Having witnesses with disabilities (e.g., one deaf and one blind are considered the same as one witness)
- The criminal admits the crime (*iqrār*), then retracts the confession with only one witness testifying to the crime.

The burden of providing proof is on the plaintiff (prosecutor or victim).

The burden of passing the judgment is on the judge, and the judge has the freedom to incriminate as *hirābah* if other alibis prove the crime rule even in the absence of two qualified witnesses (e.g., videos through surveillance cameras, DNA tests, etc.). Tne difference is:

- In the presence of two witnesses, the judge can only rule with the prescribed *hadd* in *fiqh* law, and no one has the right to offer pardon to the accused, and there is no appeal mechanism.
- In the absence of two witnesses, if the act of *hirābah* can be proven through other means, the judge has a range of punishments that he can choose from, and the Muslim ruler has the right to pardon the accused upon appeal.

Note that in the absence of two witnesses, if the act of *hirābah* cannot be proven beyond a shadow of doubt, the accused is declared innocent and set free.

All references are in Arabic only, though:

- Hanafi: *Bada'i' as-Sana'i'* (Arabic: بدائع الصنائع في ترتيب الشرائع) by [Al-Kasani](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-K%C4%81s%C4%81n%C4%AB), [Vol. 7, pp. 93](https://al-maktaba.org/book/8183/1823)
- Maliki: *Sharh Az-Zurqani* (Arabic: شرح الزرقاني على مختصر خليل وحاشية البناني) by [Abd-al-Baqi al-Zurqani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abd-al-Baqi_al-Zurqani), [Vol. 8, the gloss of pp. 191-193](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33093/3645)
- Shafi'i: *Asna al-Matālibb* (Arabic: أسنى المطالب في شرح روض الطالب) by [Zakariyya al-Ansari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zakariyya_al-Ansari), [Vol. 4, pp. 158](https://al-maktaba.org/book/11468/1706)
- Hanbali: *Al-Mughni* (Arabic: المغني لابن قدامة) by [Ibn Qudamah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Qudamah), multiple pages by topic, e.g., [Vol. 10, pp. 227](https://al-maktaba.org/book/8463/4749)

Comment: "and the judge has the freedom to incriminate as hirābah if other alibis prove the crime rule even in the absence of two qualified witnesses (e.g., videos through surveillance cameras, DNA tests, etc.)." Does that mean he can punish with the same punishment as the hadd for hirabah would be, but his verdict would be considered a matter of tazir?

Comment: @G.Bach, if the judge rules an act as _hirābah_ due to other evidence in lack of two witnesses, the _hadd_ of _hirābah_ is applied. If it is a case of exemption, then _ta'zīr_ could still be a _hadd_, or may be a _qisās_ or _diyyah_ or a combination or otherwise a different form of punishment, depending on the classification of the crime.

Comment: That's a pretty confusing situation. If the judge can rule something as hirabah that didn't meet the burden of proof for hirabah, and give the same punishment as the hadd, then what is the point of the burden of proof? And, what do you mean by "a case of exemption"? Maybe we could chat about it - while your answer is very clear on what the burden of proof is, it throws up a lot of other questions that seem more important.

Comment: @G.Bach — I agree that it is confusing. I had this clarification in the answer then decided not to include it to stay focused on the topic. Let's take it to [chat].

Comment: @G.Bach, I added clarifications.